# Python : How to insert special character

Tags: python, regex

```
Stackoverflow is best
```

I want to make:

```
"""Stackoverflow is best"""
```

How can I insert special character with regex or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: It was,  foo = [stackoverflow is best] then I made it as foo = foo[0] that's why it like this but now I want make as foo = """Stackoverflow is best"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> foo = 'Stackoverflow is best '
>>> import re
>>> foo = re.sub(r'^\s*|\s*$', r'"""', foo)
>>> foo
'"""Stackoverflow is best"""'
```

Comment: but see:
foo = [Stack is best]
foo = foo[0]
need regex for this..

just : stackoverflow should become """stackoverflow is best"""

Comment: yep, then do the above steps. See the update.

Comment: but it doesn't have '' quotations

Comment: see it has triple `"`, `'` at the first is just  for printing.

Comment: yea but the foo is actually like this : foo = [stackoverflow is best] not foo = ['stackoverflow is best']

Comment: is this `foo = [stackoverflow is best]` a string or variable? If it's a variable, you can't assign `[stackoverflow is best]` to the variable foo without single quotes.

Comment: yup we can't assign but the thing I'm scraping data and it coming as list like this [<html></html>] and I saving it in a variable. foo = [<html></html>] and then I made foo = foo[0] to remove square bracket and it became <html></html>, now Beautiful soup can access document only if it is """<html></html>"""

Comment: Can you just tell me the regex which can convert `stackoverflow is best`  to `"""stackoverflow is best"""`, and please see my question that is what i want.

Comment: regex : `^|$` , replacement string `"""`. This is what i said at the first.

Comment: so it will be like this `re.sub(r'^|$', r""", foo)`

Comment: it will be like `re.sub(r'^|$', r'"""', foo)`

Comment: it showing error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: could you post the code you tried on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote:

```
foo = '"""Stackoverflow is best"""'
```

Or you can use the escape character:

```
foo = "\"\"\"Stackoverflow is best \"\"\""
```

You don't need regex to create foo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str1 = '"""Stackoverflow is best"""' # you can interchange the double and single quotes in python 
print str1
```